# Blog page id different then in main menu

Tags: plugins, blog-page

I am using ShiftNav (it is off canvas style menu, but on my blog page, it shows a blank page. I googled and found out the following the author

> ShiftNav isn't present at all on that page, which is why it doesn't
>   display. It looks like that page is probably missing the wp_footer()
>   hook (which should be on every page just before the closing body tag).

whereas i got my get_footer() in home.php, which has wp_footer() inside get_footer();,and there isn't much of net to go with or debug the issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, the documentation for ShiftNav isn't much use as it doesn't tell you why blog ID is different than real blog menu. The workaround is to create a new menu, and assign it to ShiftNav. Weird but it works.